# django using form as a context and saving it with current user

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm making a forum kind of site where a patient can ask a question to doctors. And I'm confused about some idea. Here is my Question model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    answers = models.ManyToManyField('Answer',related_name='answer_name', blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vote = models.IntegerField() # Field that denotes the no of vote for particular question

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have created a form for asking question and that works well. What I want is that in the detail view of the question there would be the answer.

Here is my model and view for answer:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    ans_body = models.TextField()
    comments = models.ManyToManyField('Comment',related_name='answer_name', blank=True)
    count = models.IntegerField()
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ans_body
```

And view is:

```
class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):
    context = {}
    model = Question
    form_class = AnswerCreationForm
    template_name = "question-detail.html"

    def get(self, request, pk, **kwargs):

        self.pk = pk
        print self.pk

        return super(QuestionDetailView, self).get(request, pk, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuestionDetailView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['question'] = Question.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        context['form'] = AnswerCreationForm

        return context
```

Here I have passed context as form. I have created the form too and the fields are `user`, `question` and `ans_body`.

Now I want to save the `ans_body`, set `user` to the current user and `question` to the same question in detail view.

I'm stucked. I don't know what I'm doing is right. Is there any better solution?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save method of form, it similar to the models save method eg.

```
def save(self, commit=True, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user')
    self.user = user
    super(Classname, self).save(commit=True)
```